# What module is this email coming from?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Today the webmaster email account received this email:

```
From: notification@mysite.com [mailto:notification@mysite.com] 
Sent: Friday, January 09, 2015 6:27 AM
To: webmaster@mysite.com
Subject: New issue created

*New issue created :* %title
Description :
%body
nodeurl :
%node_url
```

In my database I found this in the actions table:

```
aid type    callback    parameters  description
1   system  system_send_email_action    a:3:{s:9:"recipient";s:28:"webmaster@mysite.com";s:7:"subject";s:17:"New issue created";s:7:"message";s:119:"<strong>New issue created :</strong> %title

<br/>
Description : 
<br/>
%body
<br/>
nodeurl :
<br/>
%node_url";}    Send e-mail to admins
```

Answer (score 0):

On /admin/build/trigger/user, there is a trigger called “Trigger: After a user account has been created” with an action: “Send e-mail to admins”.  On the actions page for this (admin/settings/actions/configure/1) , you will see the information that gets sent in an email